# list indices convert from strings into indices python

Tags: python

I'm getting this error TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str in this piece of code (I'm creating a game and I'm assigning some string to images.

I'm trying to get the game to add some score when the right image is hit and for that I need to get this to work and I'm a bit lost right now.

I would appreciate it if you help me!

```
    import os
import random

import pygame

pygame.font.init()

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 750
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Verb Invader")

# load images
CANTO = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("verbs", "canto.png"))
CANTAS = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("verbs", "cantas.png"))
CANTA = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("verbs", "canta.png"))
CANTAMOS = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("verbs", "cantamos.png"))
CANTAIS = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("verbs", "cantais.png"))
CANTAN = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("verbs", "cantan.png"))
CANTARE = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("verbs", "cantare.png"))
CANTARAS = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("verbs", "cantaras.png"))
CANTARA = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("verbs", "cantara.png"))
CANTAREMOS = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("verbs", "cantaremos.png"))
CANTAREIS = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("verbs", "cantareis.png"))
CANTARAN = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("verbs", "cantaran.png"))
CANTE = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("verbs", "canté.png"))
CANTASTE = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("verbs", "cantaste.png"))
CANTOO = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("verbs", "cantopasado.png"))
CANTAMOSS = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("verbs", "cantamos.png"))
CANTASTEIS = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("verbs", "cantasteis.png"))
CANTARON = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("verbs", "cantaron.png"))
CANTABA = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("verbs", "cantaba.png"))
CANTABAS = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("verbs", "cantabas.png"))
CANTABAMOS = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("verbs", "cantabamos.png"))
CANTABAIS = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("verbs", "cantabais.png"))
CANTABAN = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("verbs", "cantaban.png"))

# Player

YELLOW_SPACE_SHIP = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "player.png"))

# Lasers
RED_LASER = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "pixel_laser_red.png"))
GREEN_LASER = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "pixel_laser_green.png"))
BLUE_LASER = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "pixel_laser_blue.png"))
YELLOW_LASER = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "pixel_laser_yellow.png"))

# Background
BG = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "background-black.png")), (WIDTH, HEIGHT))

small_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 40)
main_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 40)
lost_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 60)


# this is going to represent the laser object
class Laser:
    def __init__(self, x, y, img):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.img = img
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.img)  # this is done in order to detect collision

    def draw(self, window):
        window.blit(self.img, (self.x, self.y))

    # define the velocity, if down a positive value if up a negative value
    def move(self, vel):
        self.y += vel

    # is the laser out of the screen?
    def off_screen(self, height):
        return not (self.y <= height and self.y >= 0)  # if it is not off the screen false

    # has it collided with ship?
    def collision(self, obj):
        return collide(self, obj)


# define the main ship, the ship that will be inherit by player and enemy

class Ship():
    COOLDOWN = 30  # half a second

    def __init__(self, x, y, health=100):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.health = health
        self.ship_img = None  # the images will be defined later
        self.laser_img = None
        self.lasers = []
        self.cool_down_counter = 0

    def draw(self, window):
        window.blit(self.ship_img, (self.x, self.y))
        for laser in self.lasers:
            laser.draw(window)

    # define the movement of the lasers
    def move_lasers(self, vel, obj):
        self.cooldown()  # increment cooldown counter when move the lasers
        for laser in self.lasers:  # move the laser
            laser.move(vel)
            if laser.off_screen(HEIGHT):  # delete the laser if it is off the screen
                self.lasers.remove(laser)
            elif laser.collision(obj):  # if it collides with object remove the laser
                obj.health -= 10
                self.lasers.remove(laser)

    # define the cooldown counter of the ship, handle and count it
    def cooldown(self):
        if self.cool_down_counter >= self.COOLDOWN:
            self.cool_down_counter = 0
        # only increment it if it is greater than 0
        elif self.cool_down_counter > 0:
            self.cool_down_counter += 1

    def shoot(self):
        if self.cool_down_counter == 0:
            laser = Laser(self.x, self.y, self.laser_img)
            self.lasers.append(laser)
            self.cool_down_counter = 1  # start the cooldown counter

    # it gives us the surface of the object, useful for the main loop
    def get_width(self):
        return self.ship_img.get_width()

    def get_height(self):
        return self.ship_img.get_height()


score_value = 0


def show_score():
    score = small_font.render("Score: " + str(score_value), True, (231, 50, 128))  # dark pink
    WIN.blit(score, (640, 700))


# define the player class, it inherits properties from Ship class
class Player(Ship):
    def __init__(self, x, y, health=100):
        super().__init__(x, y, health)  # call the constructor, the ship
        self.ship_img = YELLOW_SPACE_SHIP  # define the images for the Player ship
        self.laser_img = YELLOW_LASER
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(
            self.ship_img)  # make a mask out of the ship_img in order to check collisions
        self.max_health = health

    def move_lasers(self, vel, enemies):
        global score_value
        self.cooldown()
        for laser in self.lasers:  # move laser
            laser.move(vel)
            if laser.off_screen(HEIGHT):  # if the laser is off the screen remove it
                self.lasers.remove(laser)
            else:
                for enemy in enemies:  # for each object in the object list
                    if laser.collision(enemy):
                        score_value += 5  # if laser hits enemy delete the enemy
                        enemies.remove(enemy)  # if the laser hits the enemy delete the enemy and the laser

                        if laser in self.lasers:
                            self.lasers.remove(laser)

    def draw(self, window):
        super().draw(window)
        self.healthbar(window)

    def healthbar(self, window):
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0),
                         (self.x, self.y + self.ship_img.get_height() + 10, self.ship_img.get_width(), 10))
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (0, 255, 0), (
            self.x, self.y + self.ship_img.get_height() + 10,
            self.ship_img.get_width() * (self.health / self.max_health),
            10))


# define the enemy class, it will inherit properties from ship
class Enemy(Ship):
    # dictionary in which a specific image is assigned some value
    SUFFIX_MAP = [
        {"1st person singular present": (CANTO, GREEN_LASER)},
            {"2nd person singular present": (CANTAS, BLUE_LASER)},
            {"1st person plural present": (CANTAMOS, GREEN_LASER)},
            {"2nd person plural present": (CANTAIS, BLUE_LASER)},
            {"3rd person plural present": (CANTAN, GREEN_LASER)},
            {"1st person singular preterite imperfect": (CANTABA, BLUE_LASER)},
            {"2nd person sg preterite imperfect": (CANTABAS, RED_LASER)},
            {"3rd person singular preterite imperfect": (CANTABA, RED_LASER)},
            {"1st person plural preterite imperfect": (CANTABAMOS, RED_LASER)},
            {"2nd person plural preterite imperfect": (CANTABAIS, BLUE_LASER)},
            {"3rd person plural preterite imperfect": (CANTABAN, RED_LASER)},
            {"1st person singular simple preterite": (CANTE, RED_LASER)},
            {"2nd person singular simple preterite": (CANTASTE, RED_LASER)},
            {"3rd person singular simple preterite": (CANTOO, BLUE_LASER)},
            {"1st person plural simple preterite": (CANTAMOS, RED_LASER)},
            {"2nd person plural simple preterite": (CANTASTEIS, RED_LASER)},
            {"Third person plural simple preterite": (CANTARON, RED_LASER)},
            {"1st person singular future": (CANTARE, GREEN_LASER)},
            {"2nd person singular future": (CANTARAS, BLUE_LASER)},
            {"3rd person singular future": (CANTARA, GREEN_LASER)},
            {"1st person plural future": (CANTAREMOS, BLUE_LASER)},
            {"2nd person plural future": (CANTAREIS, RED_LASER)},
            {"3rd person plural future": (CANTARAN, GREEN_LASER)}
    ]


    def __init__(self, x, y, suffix, health=100):
        super().__init__(x, y, health)
        self.ship_img, self.laser_img = self.SUFFIX_MAP[suffix]
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.ship_img)

    def move(self, vel):
        self.y += vel

    def shoot(self):
        if self.cool_down_counter == 0:
            laser = Laser(self.x - 20, self.y, self.laser_img)
            self.lasers.append(laser)
            self.cool_down_counter = 1

        self.questions = [
            {"1st person singular present": (CANTO, GREEN_LASER)},
            {"2nd person singular present": (CANTAS, BLUE_LASER)},
            {"1st person plural present": (CANTAMOS, GREEN_LASER)},
            {"2nd person plural present": (CANTAIS, BLUE_LASER)},
            {"3rd person plural present": (CANTAN, GREEN_LASER)},
            {"1st person singular preterite imperfect": (CANTABA, BLUE_LASER)},
            {"2nd person sg preterite imperfect": (CANTABAS, RED_LASER)},
            {"3rd person singular preterite imperfect": (CANTABA, RED_LASER)},
            {"1st person plural preterite imperfect": (CANTABAMOS, RED_LASER)},
            {"2nd person plural preterite imperfect": (CANTABAIS, BLUE_LASER)},
            {"3rd person plural preterite imperfect": (CANTABAN, RED_LASER)},
            {"1st person singular simple preterite": (CANTE, RED_LASER)},
            {"2nd person singular simple preterite": (CANTASTE, RED_LASER)},
            {"3rd person singular simple preterite": (CANTOO, BLUE_LASER)},
            {"1st person plural simple preterite": (CANTAMOS, RED_LASER)},
            {"2nd person plural simple preterite": (CANTASTEIS, RED_LASER)},
            {"Third person plural simple preterite": (CANTARON, RED_LASER)},
            {"1st person singular future": (CANTARE, GREEN_LASER)},
            {"2nd person singular future": (CANTARAS, BLUE_LASER)},
            {"3rd person singular future": (CANTARA, GREEN_LASER)},
            {"1st person plural future": (CANTAREMOS, BLUE_LASER)},
            {"2nd person plural future": (CANTAREIS, RED_LASER)},
            {"3rd person plural future": (CANTARAN, GREEN_LASER)}
        ]

        self.current_question = None
        self.right = 0
        self.wrong = 0

    def pop_question(self):
        q = random.choice(self.questions)
        self.questions.remove(q)
        self.current_question = q
        return q

    def answer(self, answer):
        if answer == self.current_question[1]:
            self.right += 1
        else:
            self.wrong += 1


conjugations = ["1st person singular present",
                "2nd person singular present",
                "1st person plural present",
                "2nd person plural present",
                "3rd person plural present",
                "1st person singular preterite imperfect",
                "2nd person sg preterite imperfect",
                "3rd person singular preterite imperfect",
                "1st person plural preterite imperfect",
                "2nd person plural preterite imperfect",
                "3rd person plural preterite imperfect",
                "1st person singular simple preterite",
                "2nd person singular simple preterite",
                "3rd person singular simple preterite",
                "1st person plural simple preterite",
                "2nd person plural simple preterite",
                "Third person plural simple preterite",
                "1st person singular future",
                "2nd person singular future",
                "3rd person singular future",
                "1st person plural future",
                "2nd person plural future",
                "3rd person plural future"]


conjugation = random.choice(conjugations)


enemies = []



def collide(enemy, laser):
    offset_x = enemy.x - laser.x
    offset_y = enemy.y - laser.y

    return enemy.mask.overlap(laser.mask, (offset_x, offset_y)) != None

def main():
    global event
    run = True
    FPS = 60
    level = 0
    lives = 5

    enemies = []
    wave_length = 1
    enemy_vel = 1

    score_value = 0

    player_vel = 5
    laser_vel = 3

    player = Player(300, 630)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    lost = False
    lost_count = 0

    def redraw_window():
        WIN.blit(BG, (0, 0))

        lives_label = main_font.render(f"Lives: {lives}", True, (255, 255, 255))
        level_label = main_font.render(f"Level: {level}", True, (255, 255, 255))
        conjugation_label = main_font.render(f"{conjugation}", True, (0, 0, 255))  # Blue


        WIN.blit(lives_label, (10, 10))
        WIN.blit(level_label, (WIDTH - level_label.get_width() - 10, 10))
        WIN.blit(conjugation_label, (10, 700))

        for enemy in enemies:
            enemy.draw(WIN)

        player.draw(WIN)

        # this will show a message if player has lost that says "game over" and will restart the main menu
        if lost:
            lost_label = lost_font.render("Game Over", True, (255, 192, 203))
            WIN.blit(lost_label, (WIDTH / 2 - lost_label.get_width() / 2, 350))

        pygame.display.update()

    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        redraw_window()
        show_score()

        # if this happens we have lost
        if lives <= 0 or player.health <= 0:
            lost = True
            lost_count += 1
        # how long shoould the "game over" message appear in the screen, in this case 5 seconds
        if lost:
            if lost_count > FPS * 5:
                run = False
            else:
                continue
        # as soon as there are no more enemies in the screen the level is higher and there appear more enemies
        if len(enemies) == 0:
            level += 1
            wave_length += 0
            conjugation_label = main_font.render(f"{conjugation}", True, (0, 0, 255))
            WIN.blit(conjugation_label, (10, 700))
            # spawn enemies to the enemy list
            for i in range(wave_length):
                enemy = Enemy(random.randrange(50, WIDTH - 100), random.randrange(-1500, -150),
                              random.choice([conjugation]))
                enemies.append(enemy)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quit()

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and player.x - player_vel > 0:  # left
            player.x -= player_vel
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and player.x + player_vel + player.get_width() < WIDTH:  # right
            player.x += player_vel
        if keys[pygame.K_UP] and player.y - player_vel > 0:  # up
            player.y -= player_vel
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and player.y + player_vel + player.get_height() + 15 < HEIGHT:  # down
            player.y += player_vel
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            player.shoot()

        # implement the velocity of the enemies as they go down
        for enemy in enemies[:]:
            enemy.move(enemy_vel)
            enemy.move_lasers(laser_vel, player)  # define the velocity of the lasers

            if random.randrange(0, 2 * 60) == 1:
                enemy.shoot()

            if collide(enemy, player):
                player.health -= 5
                enemies.remove(enemy)


            elif enemy.y + enemy.get_height() > HEIGHT:
                lives -= 1  # less life
                score_value += 1
                enemies.remove(enemy)  # it removes the object from the enemies list, in order to increment level

        player.move_lasers(-laser_vel, enemies)


        pygame.display.update()


# define the main menu for the title font
def main_menu():
    title_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 60)
    run = True
    while run:
        WIN.blit(BG, (0, 0))
        title_label = title_font.render("Press the mouse to begin...", True, (255, 192, 203))  # pink
        WIN.blit(title_label, (WIDTH / 2 - title_label.get_width() / 2, 250))
        pygame.display.update()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                main()
    pygame.quit()


main_menu()
```

the error message that I get is this. I am new to python and have been stuck on how to do the question-answering part

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kvach\Desktop\Space-Shooter-Tutorial\Space Shooter Tutorial\AGHH.py", line 435, in <module>
    main_menu()
  File "C:\Users\kvach\Desktop\Space-Shooter-Tutorial\Space Shooter Tutorial\AGHH.py", line 431, in main_menu
    main()
  File "C:\Users\kvach\Desktop\Space-Shooter-Tutorial\Space Shooter Tutorial\AGHH.py", line 373, in main
    enemy = Enemy(random.randrange(50, WIDTH - 100), random.randrange(-1500, -150),
  File "C:\Users\kvach\Desktop\Space-Shooter-Tutorial\Space Shooter Tutorial\AGHH.py", line 210, in __init__
    self.ship_img, self.laser_img = self.SUFFIX_MAP[suffix]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Please add code where you are getting error

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! Could you give us your full code, please? And give us the full error with the line number? It seems like you are building a list of dictionaries, which is a bit strange to say the least but that may be a quirk of Pygames. Are you new to python?

Comment: We may need to know what you've put in your constants "CANTARAN, GREEN_LASER, ..." to be able to help you.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your "SUFFIX_MAP", so long as we have a value for those constants, it compiles. The error is somewhere else. Please give us your code. :)

Comment: @Florian *NO!* We _explicitly_ discourage _full code_. It is OP's job to do some debugging, narrow down the problem to a [mre], and ask a _specific_ question. The people volunteering their time here don't need to spend it reading line after line of irrelevant code. Useful reading: [tour], [ask], [what's on-topic](/help/on-topic). You should instead ask for more _relevant_ code and error stack traces.

Comment: @paranav Hosangadi You're right. Well... I guess the full error and "a bit more code" would have been a more appropriate thing to ask for. I'll be careful not to spoil newbies in the future. :)

Comment: As an aside, I'd recommend wrapping your image loading tasks in a `load_image(file_name, loc="verbs")` function or something, so that `pygame.image.load(os.path.join("verbs", x))` becomes `load_image(x)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a list, somewhere, which wants to eat an integer but instead you are feeding it a string.

Since your error is located around SUFFIX_MAP and since SUFFIX_MAP is used only in the enemy class... the issue is in enemy's `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, x, y, suffix, health=100):
    super().__init__(x, y, health)
    print(suffix)
    self.ship_img, self.laser_img = self.SUFFIX_MAP[suffix] # <- BUG!
    self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.ship_img)
```

If you print suffix, you will see that it gives you something like "Third person plural simple preterite" (one type of enemy for the uninformed reader). but here is the datatype of SUFFIX_MAP:

```
SUFFIX_MAP = [{'key': (val1, val2)}]
```

It is a `list( of dict( of tuple()))`. And a list works like this:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
result = my_list[0] # index 0 being a.
print(result) # Prints a.
```

you just have to transform SUFFIX_MAP into a dictionary and you'll be good to go!

```
SUFFIX_MAP = {
        "1st person singular present": (CANTO, GREEN_LASER),
        "2nd person singular present": (CANTAS, BLUE_LASER),
        "1st person plural present": (CANTAMOS, GREEN_LASER),
        "2nd person plural present": (CANTAIS, BLUE_LASER),
        "3rd person plural present": (CANTAN, GREEN_LASER),
        "1st person singular preterite imperfect": (CANTABA, BLUE_LASER),
        "2nd person sg preterite imperfect": (CANTABAS, RED_LASER),
        "3rd person singular preterite imperfect": (CANTABA, RED_LASER),
        "1st person plural preterite imperfect": (CANTABAMOS, RED_LASER),
        "2nd person plural preterite imperfect": (CANTABAIS, BLUE_LASER),
        "3rd person plural preterite imperfect": (CANTABAN, RED_LASER),
        "1st person singular simple preterite": (CANTE, RED_LASER),
        "2nd person singular simple preterite": (CANTASTE, RED_LASER),
        "3rd person singular simple preterite": (CANTOO, BLUE_LASER),
        "1st person plural simple preterite": (CANTAMOS, RED_LASER),
        "2nd person plural simple preterite": (CANTASTEIS, RED_LASER),
        "Third person plural simple preterite": (CANTARON, RED_LASER),
        "1st person singular future": (CANTARE, GREEN_LASER),
        "2nd person singular future": (CANTARAS, BLUE_LASER),
        "3rd person singular future": (CANTARA, GREEN_LASER),
        "1st person plural future": (CANTAREMOS, BLUE_LASER),
        "2nd person plural future": (CANTAREIS, RED_LASER),
        "3rd person plural future": (CANTARAN, GREEN_LASER)
    }
```

Comment: I edited the post and now the whole code is in. I am new to python yes and I can't figure out how to do this correctly, I know that my code looks messy but I can't do better right now

Comment: Much appreciated! Don't feel bad about your code, it's pretty good in fact, it's readable!

Comment: btw, answer updated, the culprit was the list brackets [] around the SUFFIX_MAP.

Comment: Thank you very much! And sorry for the trouble, I did it like that and it works now. Thank you :)